# How to generate library or framework from source code added as submodule?

Tags: ios, git-submodules

I'm not sure what should I call it – so kindly asking this in a readable language. Please let me ask if you need to know more about it.

I've got an iOS app to work. It was a way old project. I have found that it has all third party library added as submodules. For e.g. `FacebookiOSSDK.framework` has been missing but source of `FacebookiOSSDK` is exist. The same way, `libgpuimage.a`is missing but all source files available.

I think, I need to generate (or create) those lib and framework file to add them back into the project. I don't know what should I call? What's the issue? What I understand is right or wrong? Anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the copy of libGPUImage you have doesn't have armv7s symbols included in it.

You need to recompile, or re-download and then recompile, the GPUImage opensource library from GitHub. [Click here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

GPUImage needs a few other frameworks to be linked into your application, so you'll need to add the following as linked libraries in your application target:

> CoreMedia
>
> CoreVideo
>
> OpenGLES
>
> AVFoundation
>
> QuartzCore

you may need to add **-ObjC** to your Other Linker Flags in your project's build settings.